# get rescourceBundle "com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.metal.resources.metal" in Java 10

Tags: java, swing, resourcebundle, java-platform-module-system, java-10

i am trying to get an running Java8 application to get it run under java10.

```
ResourceBundle bundle1 = ResourceBundle.getBundle ( "com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.metal.resources.metal" );
```

In Java 8 everything works fine, but in java10 i get the following message:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: unnamed module can't load
>   com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.metal.resources.metal in module
>   java.desktop

so i read a little bit about jigsaw and so i find to add the following JavaVm attributes:

```
--add-opens=java.desktop/com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.metal.resources=ALL-UNNAMED

--add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.metal.resources=ALL-UNNAMED
```

but even with these attibutes i get the same error

Comment: `com.sun.` Note well: `Classes from "com.sun.*" and "sun.*" packages should not be used`

Comment: @AndrewThompson i know that they should not be used, but adding the explained attributes to the JavaVM the should be accessible, but they doesn't, thats the reason why I ask the question here.

Comment: com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.metal.resources.metal needs to be open'ed unconditional, meaning to all modules. There is no way to do this on the command line.

Comment: @AlanBateman thank you for your answer, but how do I do it?

Comment: @AlanBateman , after a lot of try and error, i found out that the combination of --add-opens=java.desktop/com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.metal.resources=ALL-UNNAMED and ResourceBundle bundle1 = ResourceBundle.getBundle( "com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.metal.resources.metal", Object.class.getModule() ); will work, but I don#t understand why using ResourceBundle bundle2 = ResourceBundle.getBundle( "com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.metal.resources.metal" ) won't work